# RuntimeError: Mmap of '/home/pi/object-detector/model' failed

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, google-coral

I am using Raspberry pi 4 Model B, armv7l, with Raspbian stretch. I am having one 'mobilenet_v2_1.0_224_quant_edgetpu.tflite' model which I want to run with the google coral edge TPU. When I am trying to run the model it fails. I am using a standard Raspberry Pi V2 camera.

What can be the reason (not enough memory, TPU is damaged, the model is not prepared properly )? How can I get to know the edge TPU is working or not? How can I fix it?

Her is the traceback call:

```
 pi@raspberrypi:~/object-detector $ python3 detect_object_video_edge.py --model  
/home/pi/object-mask-detector/model --labels /home/pi/object-detector/model/object_labels.txt
[INFO] parsing class labels...
[INFO] loading Coral model...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "detect_object_video_edge.py", line 29, in <module>
model = DetectionEngine(args["model"])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/edgetpu/detection/engine.py", line 73, in __init__
super().__init__(model_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/edgetpu/basic/basic_engine.py", line 92, in __init__
    self._engine = BasicEnginePythonWrapper.CreateFromFile(model_path)
RuntimeError: Mmap of '/home/pi/object-detector/model' failed.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
--model /home/pi/object-mask-detector/model
```

and

```
RuntimeError: Mmap of '/home/pi/object-detector/model' failed.
```

suggested that you are giving the api a directory, not a model.

Answer (score 0):

we can't guess your configuration

follow this tutorial..

Look here : [github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection](https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-on-the-Raspberry-Pi)